# ASP.NET Form inside another Form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an old ASP.NET application which is still under use and cannot change its structure due to its complexity. In this application I encounter a Form within Form scenario. The thing is like

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         ........
         ........
         <form id="form2" runat="server">
            .................
            .................
         </form>
    </form>
```

"form1" and "form2" are still under two different aspx files but when used with ModalPopup one form is created inside another as described above. And the real problem is when closing the inner form. I cannot close the inner form and when I try its not getting closed. Since there is an inner form for "form1" and exception occurs namely "theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX is null or not an object". I can trace the error in IE but no solution found without altering the structure of inner forms.

Comment: HTML doesn't allow a form to be inside another form. All you can do is to fake the behaviour with positioning, but I'd rather suggest to re-plan your forms.

Comment: Thanks Max. So you mean no way to dispose the "form2" created inside "form1" after a specific time of execution? It would be so great to get a solution.

Comment: @Anoop not only can you not put a form inside another form, but you can only have one form with `runat="server"` visible (the code-behind `Visible` not just visible in the DOM) at any given time (whether they are separated, or improperly nested like you have). You have to take a different approach.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but still I can have these forms under one another and is running correctly. No functionality is adversely effected, but after hiding the "form2" I cannot click Submit button in the "form1" which is due to the  "theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX is null or not an object". So I believe its due to only one problem i.e I cannot close "form2" once it is created in the DOM, only I can do is to hide it.

Comment: @Anoop If you feel you need two nested forms, that's probably because you want more complex interactivity. But in this case, it's better to switch to another technology, like AJAX. AJAX needs Javascript to work, and some users may have it switched off, but it's becoming quite rare nowadays and you might legitimately think to ditch their support in favor of a better user experience, or fallback to a crummy one.

Comment: Ya Max I am gonna alter the pages tomorrow for a clean and adaptable environment. I cannot go with this crummy one. I always stick to the proper way of coding and that's what I am gonna do tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your support buddy.